# I want to run custom JS but browser says its unsafe and wont load it without allowing script manually in browser

Tags: javascript, hosting

So, I made a script which shows loading gif and only when all elements are loaded it will show the website, however its stuck on loading because browser says its unsafe script.. I want to make it safe! Is that somehow possible?

When I allow it in chrome to load it loads but I want to have it safe so people doesnt have to click and enable the "unsafe scripts" xD

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$("#seprecon").fadeOut("fast");
});
</script>
```

I expect to make the script safe and load it on all browsers without problems.

Comment: The script you posted would not trigger an "unsafe" warning.

Comment: @Pointy it would if the page has CSP that says no inline scripts are allowed without a valid nonce attribute.

Comment: @Nate yes that's a good point; it's possible it's part of some boilerplate the OP is using

Comment: @Pointy yeah, a lot of frameworks do that now. Like, Ruby On Rails ships with CSP enabled which is not an issue as long as you use their `javascript_tag` helper method, which automatically handles adding the `nonce` token for you. But if you start manually building the <script> tag yourself, you’re gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Here’s some documentation to read up on. But without knowing more, it’s hard to tell you if this is even the problem. (That’s why this is a comment and not an answer.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code... except for the bad indentation :)

Please give a look here. https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Google-Chrome-show-Load-unsafe-script-on-my-website-although-there-is-nothing-wrong-with-the-script

Maybe one you're adding one of your library mixing http and https

Comment: Thanks dude just had to change jquery src from http:// to https://, Thank you guys!!

Comment: Cool... please take care of your indentation though